# Why does my Update() method no longer work the moment I move it into a parent class?

Tags: java, libgdx

I have three objects using the same functions and variables: just different images. So I decided to move them into a parent class called Entity. They still can render the same images and stuff but suddenly, my Update() method which moves the objects using keypresses no longer works. I'm not very sure why that's the case because to me, the idea of parent class is to store things the child class would use.

my parent class

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class Entity{
    public Vector2 position;
    public Sprite sprite;
    public float speed;
    public Entity(Texture img){
        sprite = new Sprite(img);
        position = new Vector2();
    }

    public void Update(float deltaTime){
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)) position.x-=deltaTime*speed;
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)) position.x+=deltaTime*speed;
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S)) position.y-=deltaTime*speed;
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W)) position.y+=deltaTime*speed;
    }
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch batch){
        Update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        sprite.setPosition(position.x, position.y);
        sprite.draw(batch);
    }
}
```

my child class

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class Object1 extends Entity{

    public Object1(Texture img){
        super(img);
        super.position = new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/10,0);
    }


}
```

I found out that the key presses work, but it can't seem to update the position of the image. I thought functions in parent classes are essentially functions in child classes so I don't know why it can't be updated.

Comment: Is `speed` ever set?

Comment: @TimMoore yup speed is set

Comment: Use the debugger to see exactly what's happening in `Update`.

Comment: At least, do not create a new object for a position, instead, just set the value. //line Entity super.position = new Vector2... ->position.set...